# How do I display text using jQuery without having it disappear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-events

How do I display text using jQuery without having it disappear?

When the user types in a number. I then want to display a certain message - You're hot cold warm etc. Right now the message flashes into the screen, but I want it to stay and then the user can continue playing until he gives up and wants to display the random number or reset the game.

The only thing relevant in the html is:

```
    <div class="output-container">

    </div>
```

which is where I want to display the message.

Here is the application.js:

```
// Hot or Cold JS game.
$(document).ready(function() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100 ) + 1);

    $('#Enter').click(function() {
        var guessNumber = document.getElementById('number');
        var difference = Math.abs(guessNumber - randomNumber);
        
        if (difference == 0) {
            // Display to user - "Perfect"
            $('.output-container').append('Perfect');
        } else if (difference < 5) {
            // Display to user - You're on Fire!
            $('.output-container').append('You are on Fire!');
        } else if (difference < 10) {
            // Display to user - Warm
            $('.output-container').append('Warm');
        } else if (difference < 30) {
            // Display to user - Ice Cold
            $('.output-container').append('Ice Cold');
        } else {
            // Display to user - You must be Frozen?
            $('.output-container').append('You must be Frozen!');
        };
    });
    
    // Start over
    $('#reset').click(function() {
        location.reload();
    });
    $('#show').click(function() {
        $('#show').hide();
        $('#append-number').append(randomNumber);
    });
});
```

Comment: Why are you using jQuery and still using `document.getElementById` ?

Comment: Please make a fiddle: jsfiddle.net

Comment: Are you elements in a form by any chance, and you are reloading the page accidentally when a button is clicked? Because I  don't see a reason why the text should not persist. Note that `guessNumber - randomNumber` is certainly wrong though. You cannot subtract a number from a *DOM element*.

Comment: What is the application currently doing? You aren't explaining any of it's behavior, and the code looks fine depending on what you're asking.... If you aren't more specific, people will have a hard time helping you, if they can at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Quick demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brZw7/)

### Changes to Javascript:

```
var guessNumber = document.getElementById('number').value;
...
// $('.output-container').append(...)  // BAD
$('.output-container').text(...)  //GOOD
```

And either make `#Enter` be a plain `type="button"` or add `return false;` at the end of the `.click()` handler.  Otherwise it's going to keep submitting and reloading the page.

Comment: The demo was very helpful.

Comment: Happy to be of service

Comment: Oh yeah add this at the beginning of your JS after `$(document).ready()`  -->  `$('#number').on('keyup keypress', function(e) { if (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) return false; });` that will restrict character input to only numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly [as I assumed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324922/how-do-i-display-text-using-jquery-without-having-it-disappear/21325142#comment32144944_21324922), you have the buttons inside the form and clicking them reloads the page. Change the type of the button to `button`:

```
<button type="button" ... >Enter</button>
```

*or* [prevent the default event](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) (submitting the form) from taking place:

```
$('#Enter').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

});
```

However, if you don't want to use the "Enter" button as submit button, don't specify it as one.

---

Note that there are other problems with your code, but that's out of the scope of this question.

Comment: yeah i think the logic somewhere is wrong because the same message keeps popping up

Comment: The help is very appreciated

Comment: As I said, you cannot subtract a number from a DOM element. You have to get the value of that element first.